# Excel: Lookup All Matching Values and place in comma separated list?

Tags: excel, vba, indexing, match

I have a Data sheet like so:

```
Col A    Col B    Col C    Column D   Col E   Column F     Col G    Col H      Col  I    Col J     Col K    
                           1234               Supplier 1
                           2222               Supplier 2
                           3333               Supplier 2
                           4444               Supplier 1
```

I also have another sheet

```
Home sheet:

Column B
Supplier 1   <-- Values Produced From Index Match Formula
Supplier 2
```

I want to list all of the item numbers from column D, Data sheet, where the supplier name on Home sheet matches.

However, i want to place all of the matching item numbers in one cell, in a comma separated list like so:

```
Home sheet:    

Column B         Column C
Supplier 1       1234, 4444
Supplier 2       2222, 3333
```

At the moment i am doing this using a user defined function in vba:

```
Function SingleCellExtract(LookupValue As String, LookupRange As Range, ColumnNumber As Integer, Char As String)
'Updateby20150824
    Dim I As Long
    Dim xRet As String
    For I = 1 To LookupRange.Columns(1).Cells.Count
        If LookupRange.Cells(I, 1) = LookupValue Then
            If xRet = "" Then
                xRet = LookupRange.Cells(I, ColumnNumber) & Char
            Else
                xRet = xRet & "" & LookupRange.Cells(I, ColumnNumber) & Char
            End If
        End If
    Next
    SingleCellExtract = Left(xRet, Len(xRet) - 1)
End Function
```

And then using the following formula to get the result:

```
=SingleCellExtract(B14,Data!F:F,-1,",")
```

This works, however, I have more than 500 lines of data and this method takes about 10 minutes or more to calculate - and sometimes causes the sheet to crash.

Please can someone show me a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An immediate improvement would be to put the data into an array rather than referencing the cells for each check:

```
Function SingleCellExtract(LookupValue As String, LookupRange As Range, LookupCol As Long, ReturnCol As Long, Char As String)
'Updateby20150824
    Dim varTMP As Variant, I As Long
    varTMP = LookupRange
    Dim xRet As String
    For I = 1 To UBound(varTMP, 1)
        If varTMP(I, LookupCol) = LookupValue Then
            If xRet = "" Then
                xRet = varTMP(I, ReturnCol)
            Else
                xRet = xRet & Char & varTMP(I, ReturnCol)
            End If
        End If
    Next
    SingleCellExtract = xRet
End Function
```

I also amended your return line and xRet logic to avoid the need for left/len.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, however this only seems to work for the first cell and then causes all the other cells down the column to display #VALUE errors

Comment: It works fine in testing on my end, however one flaw with the logic of the existing function is it expects the lookup column to be the first column of the source data. I've edited the answer to split out the lookup and return column parameters. This amended function works perfectly on the data structure you have given. (http://i.imgur.com/TmTea9d.png)

Comment: well i don't know what i'm doing different but it simply won't work for me. It keeps saying #Value. i've restarted excel, i've checked the cells are calculating. If it works for you i'm not sure why it won't work for me. Are you using excel 2013, as that's what i'm using if that makes a difference.

Comment: does it matter that i have column E in between Column D and F on my data sheet?

Comment: Having column E between would be fine. Am I to assume your formula looks like this? (An example row range of course) =SingleCellExtract(B2,Data!$D$1:$F$500,3,1,",")

Comment: no i was using the original formula =SingleCellExtract(B14,Data!F:F,-1,","). How come i need to change the formula? Should this matter?

Comment: That would explain the issue, you'd be using a single column (index 1) as the source data and then asking it to return column (1-0) = 0 (doesn't exist). Use the new formula and the new function.

Comment: just seems to be blank now. See edited question. I have more columns in my range on data sheet

Answer (score 0):

I hope my solution is interesting to you, here it goes:
If you are sort your data by two columns you are using, it would look something like this:

```
SupplierID  Text
1           Foo
1           Bar
1           FooBar
2           Foo
2           Bar
2           FooBar
```

Now just add this formula into `Result` column:

```
=IF(A2<>A1,B2,CONCATENATE(C1,", ",B2))
```

This will create output like this one:

```
SupplierID  Text    Result
1           Foo     Foo
1           Bar     Foo, Bar
1           FooBar  Foo, Bar, FooBar
2           Foo     Foo
2           Bar     Foo, Bar
2           FooBar  Foo, Bar, FooBar
```

Finally you can apply copy the same text in all columns.
I hope this helps!